# Help me escape this php/js and stop warning error on zend studio

Tags: php, jquery

This shouldn't be too difficult but for the life of my cant sort it out and its driving me mad.

```
$script = "
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.row').hover(function() {
        var id = ($(this).attr('id').replace(/\D/g, ''));
        $('.row-edit-' + id).css('display', 'block');
            }, function() {
        var id = ($(this).attr('id').replace(/\D/g, ''));
        $('.row-edit-' + id).css('display', 'none');
    });
});
";
```

So its a bit of jquery inside a php tag, might be horrible to look at but as I'm using it sparingly its not too bad.

If anyone here has studio or eclipse could they give it a quick fix?

Thanks,

Daniel

Comment: What is the result you see when running this?

Comment: studio complains that there is a bad escape sequence at `(/\D/g, ''));`. The code work fine its just my IDE being fussy and its a) annoying b) keeps the entire project clean so I can pinpoint real errors/typos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$script = <<<EOD
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.row').hover(function() {
        var id = ($(this).attr('id').replace(/\D/g, ''));
        $('.row-edit-' + id).css('display', 'block');
            }, function() {
        var id = ($(this).attr('id').replace(/\D/g, ''));
        $('.row-edit-' + id).css('display', 'none');
    });
});
EOD;
```

Taken from here [PHP Strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

*Edit: Sorry, I made a typo, corrected it now!*

Comment: line before `EOD;` (`";`) should not be there. should it be there?

Comment: should not have the `";` on the penultimate line, but apart from that its very good!